# Symfony2: add class to every select

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to customize Symfony2 form rendering to add a class to every select that is generated.
I thought that having a custom form_div_layout.html.twig with:

```
{% block choice_widget_collapsed %}
{% spaceless %}
    <select class='myclass' {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %}>
    {% if empty_value is not none %}
        <option value="">{{ empty_value|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</option>
    {% endif %}
    {% if preferred_choices|length > 0 %}
        {% set options = preferred_choices %}
        {{ block('choice_widget_options') }}
        {% if choices|length > 0 and separator is not none %}
            <option disabled="disabled">{{ separator }}</option>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {% set options = choices %}
    {{ block('choice_widget_options') }}
</select>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_collapsed %}
```

and using it with

```
{% form_theme form 'YOPYourOwnPoetBundle:Form:form_div_layout.html.twig' %}
```

would do the trick.

However, the class 'myclass' isn't added to the select.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you passing any additional classes by chance? It would help if you also pasted the generated html here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first make sure the theme file you're trying to use has the same name as the name you're using in the `form_theme` expression and that the file really is there. I can't remember off top of my head whether Twig throws an exception or not in case these do not match.

In addition, you might be accidentally passing a `class` attribute either when building a form or rendering it. What happens is that your element now has two `class` attributes.

A workaround is to actually add your new class to the collection of existing ones.

```
{% block choice_widget_collapsed %}
{% spaceless %}
{% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required'}) %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('') ~ ' myclass')|trim}) %}
    <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %}>
    {# ... #}
</select>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_collapsed %}
```

This allows you to add any optional class you might need for specific elements later on.

**EDIT**

Looking at the Sf2 Github repsitory it seems that the theme file has been recently changed. In versions 2.0.* you should be overriding [`choice_widget`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.0.15/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L43), in versions 2.1.* the correct block is [`choice_widget_collapsed`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L65).

Comment: You got that right! I'm using Symfony2.0.14 so I was looking at the wrong version of the file form_div_layout.html.twig. Adding a class='myclass' to choice_widget instead of choice_widget_collapsed works. Besides, your solution to use {% set attr = attr|merge({class: 'myclass' ~ (attr.class is defined ? ' ' ~ attr.class : '')}) %} works too, that's what i'm gonna use. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should either change the form theme line to:

```
{% form_theme form 'YOPYourOwnPoetBundle:Form:form_div_layout.html.twig' %}
```

or you need to change the name of your twig file into fields.html.twig

Both have to match.

Comment: The template name is irrelevant.

Comment: @gilden If you try to "load" a new twig template via form_theme the name of the template file should match the name you want to load shouldn't it, otherwise there will be no file to load

Comment: Not a single time have I had to name my form theme template `form_div_layout.html.twig`. Even the cookbook article uses a different template name in [the example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-2-inside-a-separate-template).

Comment: The only thing I said was that the name of your template file must match the name you use when you load it via form_theme. Thats exactly as described in the documentation you have linked. Both (the name of the template file and the name in form_theme) are the same (fields.html.twig)

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad. Guess I'm still sleeping :)

Comment: Yes my file fields.html.twig is definitely taken into account. I'll edit my question with some more info